# Lock close and minimize on electron js (Ubuntu)

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, electron

I want to lock close and minimize on electron js desktop app.

This application is for ubuntu, but I have read on electron's web site the following:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1X6W.png)

Electron website: [electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions)

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the follwing code at the browser object inorder to avoid the top bar.

```js
const browserWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  frame: false,
  ...
})
```